# Cant start android wear emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, wear-os, android-virtual-device

i am trying to start android wear emulator with android studio but it is giving the following error :

[image: ERROR]

how can I start the wear emulator? I want to start learning wear programming.

thank you in advance

Comment: you need to install hardware acceleration. google it. the very first link shows how to install.

Comment: Just increase your AVD's Ram size & http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/devices/emulator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. update **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)**
   [image]
2. After installing the installer, you have to run it to install it on your system. Open the directory where your Android SDK is located. Go inside the extras\Intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager directory and you should see the intelhaxm-android.exe file.
   [image]

Also make sure you have enabled **Virtualization Technology** in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

1.Please make sure the `HAXM` is installed.

[image]

2.turn on the CPU virtualization option in you computer BIOS.

3.Increase the RAM size of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

First refere to this link to create a wear 
http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#SetupEmulator

And you have to enable CPU virtualization in your computer bios .